# Equivalente de «finite verb» del inglés en español.

Tags: verbos

¿Alguien podría ayudarme en esto?
Entiendo que el equivalente es cuando el verbo es usado en un estado conjugado, diferente a su uso como infinitivo y gerundio. 
Alguna opinión por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se llaman verbos en **forma personal**. En español las formas *impersonales* son tres: el infinitivo, el gerundio y el participio. Todas las demás formas son formas personales.

Ojo: es diferente un verbo personal, que admite sujeto, a un verbo en forma personal, que es una flexión del verbo.